# Does a Java plugin exist for Qt Creator

Tags: java, qt-creator

I am struggling to find a plugin which would allow me to use Java in Qt Creator. My questions are:

1. Does a plugin like that even exist?
2. If it doesn't exist, why not? Is there some wider conflict between Java and Qt?

Thanks in advance,

Ernesto

Comment: This would be glorious. Qt Creator is snappy on ten year old hardware where as Eclipse still feels sluggish on the latest.

Comment: Small update: latest versions have a Java plugin though I can't say how good it is. Frankly, I'm not a big fan of turning Qt Creator into IDE that supports multiple languages. At least not that fast. The Python support is minimalistic at best and they are now starting to add support for Java? First they need polish the Python support then go with Java or dump the Python for now and concentrate on Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's not possible at the moment - it can do C++ only...
Maybe they'll add Java support in future, who knows :)

Answer (score 3):

Syntax highlighting for Java works on a basic level, there is no code completion. "Properly" supported are currently only C++, QML, GSLS, and JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to add a QT-Java support to some IDE like eclipse?
If so, there is already plugins supported for Jambi.
Check [this](http://qt.nokia.com/developer/eclipse-integration) for how to integerate QT Jambi with eclipse IDE

If this is not what you want, would you make the question more detailed:)

Comment: Yes, sorry... I updated my question. What I want to do is be able to write Java applications using Qt creator [not just Jambi or normal Qt applications, but Java apps as well]; it does not matter to me if there are UI designer support, but at least language code highlights and code completion would be nice features.

Comment: @ebasconp...hmmm, i have never come across one!

Answer (score 1):

You have to download qt-eclipse-integration setup and install it...
now ou can compile java programs in QT.

Comment: A link would be a plus...